# Label appears completely different in Layout-view than in exported image in QGIS using maptiler plugin

Tags: qgis, labeling, vector-tiles, maptiler

I'm using the maptiler vector tiles plugin in QGIS to have a base map that I can style a bit. There is a problem however.

I'm seeing this in the layout-view:
[image]

I don't like that the line to the overview map is crossing the label. I also don't know how to resolve this one. I tried manually moving the label. But as far as I know I can't set this helper-line to be an obstacle, can I?

But what I want to change is the symbology of the country names in the exported PNG.
The exported map looks like this:
[image]

There must be an option to change that, but I just don't know how. I can go in the label properties dialog of the 'Bright' map tiler layer, but there I don't know what to change specifically. I'd really like to understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

To fix country label size try to change label units from pixels to points. How to do that is described in plugin-repository https://github.com/maptiler/qgis-maptiler-plugin/issues/137

However you can't move just one single label manually. Label position is encoded as a point in pbf tile. You can try to open Layer Styling panel (F7) and set an offset for whole layer of labels. In your case it is a layer that shows country labels. You can press F7, click to Labels tab, double-click on label_country layer and then click on Placement tab. Here, you can set an offset for the labels but it effects all labels in selected layer country_label, so there will be offset for Chile and for Argentina as well.