# MapTiler labels plotting too small in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, maptiler

I am using MapTiler vector tiles to show roads and suburb names in QGIS. If I export to pdf from a layout, the road names and suburb names show okay (albeit smaller than what is shown onscreen in QGIS). But if I plot directly to the plotter from QGIS (using the exact same QGIS layout), the road names and suburb names are so small that they can barely be seen, never mind being able to read them. Reducing the plot resolution in the QGIS layout increases the size of the road names and suburb names, but results in jagged text. I have experienced this issue in both 3.14 and 3.16.

I know that one possible solution is to display the basemap without the road names and suburb names and generate the names separately, but the fact that the road names and suburb names in the pdf file are significantly larger than those in the direct plot from QGIS suggests that QGIS is playing a role, not just the basemap itself.

The problem is similar to this one:
[Label appears completely different in Layout-view than in exported image in QGIS using maptiler plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375958/label-appears-completely-different-in-layout-view-than-in-exported-image-in-qgis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Layer Styling Panel (F7 shortcut) and click on the Labels tab. Here you can modify labels setting for any layer. I would suggest you to try change size unit from Pixel to Points or vice versa as I know that might cause some issues on HighRes displayes. If not, just change the size of labels.

Comment: Excellent. For anyone finding this topic in the future, once you open the Layer Styling Panel (F7), then click on the Labels tab, the final step is to click on the "Edit current rule" button down the bottom. Then you can change the setting from Pixels to Points and change the font size etc.

Comment: I've just played with this a bit further and changing from Points to Pixels changes the font size on the plotted output, but changing the label size makes no difference. Clicking on the button to the right of the size setting gives access to some new settings. The default settings are driven by an algorithm which captures zoom level amongst other things. I clicked on the Assistant label at the bottom of the list of options and this gave further options again. Changing the values in the "Output from" and "to" boxes allowed me to get the desired label font size in the plotted output.

Comment: For me it just says "This renderer doesn't implement a graphical interface". All I can do is set the oversampling to a lower number but that makes the output blurry.